# Updating Datatable as Datasource

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, datagrid

I'm using a data table as a data source for a data grid in VB.NET.

```
Public Property InterimLotTable As DataTable

uxDataGridAuditSamplerView.DataSource = SamplerParent.InterimLotTable
```

But when I update the `SamplerParent.InterimLotTable` its not reflected in my dataGrid.

Here is the code where I update the Datatable.

```
 Dim sql = String.Format("select * from CAMS.VW_BL_TAS_InterimLotData where PARENTLOT = '{0}'", ParentLot)
    Dim dynaset = db.CreateDynaset(sql, DBWrapper.DynasetOptions.ORADYN_READONLY)

    InterimLotTable = dynaset.CopyToDataTable()
```

I thought that with the databinding when I made changes to the `InterimLotTable` the datagrid would be updated automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not updating InterimLotTable, you're replacing it - i.e. the property now returns a different object.

The controls that are bound to the old object don't know anything has happened, as the object they have a reference to, *hasn't changed*.

You could use an intermediate `BindingSource`, or raise an event so the UI can choose to rebind as appropriate